# Syntax error in Gruntfile.js?

Tags: magento2, javascript, theme, magento2.2.2, grunt

I can't seem to be able to use Grunt to compile my less files in my custom theme. I have done all steps described in [the documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/tools/using_grunt.html).

My theme name is "alliance" so here is what I am trying to do and the output:

```
$ grunt clean:alliance

/Users/admin/Sites/new/docroot/node_modules/node-minify/node_modules/babel-preset-babili/lib/index.js:32
      get() {
         ^
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
Warning: Task "clean:alliance" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I am using an exact copy of the [Gruntfile.js.sample](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/2.2/Gruntfile.js.sample) file which I renamed to `Gruntfile.js` and which doesn't seem to contain any syntax error, so I am a bit lost with this error message.

Any idea? Is there an issue with the current version of the Gruntfile or am I doing something wrong?

I am using Magento 2.2.2 on Docker for Mac and running this command on my host machine. The folder `/Users/admin/Sites/new/docroot` is mounted to my container's root folder with the `:delegated` flag, if that is useful information.

Here is the content of my `themes.js` file:

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

'use strict';

/**
 * Define Themes
 *
 * area: area, one of (frontend|adminhtml|doc),
 * name: theme name in format Vendor/theme-name,
 * locale: locale,
 * files: [
 * 'css/styles-m',
 * 'css/styles-l'
 * ],
 * dsl: dynamic stylesheet language (less|sass)
 *
 */
module.exports = {
    blank: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Magento/blank',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l',
            'css/email',
            'css/email-inline'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
    luma: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Magento/luma',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
    alliance: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Udg/alliance',
        locale: 'en_GB',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
    backend: {
        area: 'adminhtml',
        name: 'Magento/backend',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-old',
            'css/styles'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    }
};
```

I just tried running Grunt with `--verbose` option and here is the output:

```
$ grunt --verbose
Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose

Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.

/Users/admin/Sites/new/docroot/node_modules/node-minify/node_modules/babel-preset-babili/lib/index.js:32
      get() {
         ^
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
>>   at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
>>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>>   at Module.load (/Users/admin/Sites/new/docroot/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/coffeescript/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
>>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>>   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>>   at require (module.js:380:17)
>>   at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Sites/new/docroot/node_modules/node-minify/lib/compressors/babili.js:15:25)
>>   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>>   at Module.load (/Users/admin/Sites/new/docroot/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/coffeescript/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
>>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>>   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>>   at require (module.js:380:17)
>>   at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Sites/new/docroot/node_modules/node-minify/lib/compress.js:16:14)
>>   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>>   at Module.load (/Users/admin/Sites/new/docroot/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/coffeescript/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
>>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>>   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>>   at require (module.js:380:17)
>>   at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Sites/new/docroot/node_modules/node-minify/lib/node-minify.js:15:16)
>>   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>>   at Module.load (/Users/admin/Sites/new/docroot/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/coffeescript/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
>>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>>   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>>   at require (module.js:380:17)
>>   at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Sites/new/docroot/node_modules/node-minify/index.js:9:18)
>>   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>>   at Module.load (/Users/admin/Sites/new/docroot/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/coffeescript/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
>>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>>   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>>   at require (module.js:380:17)
>>   at module.exports (/Users/admin/Sites/new/docroot/dev/tools/grunt/tasks/mage-minify.js:8:23)
>>   at /Users/admin/Sites/new/docroot/Gruntfile.js:25:22
>>   at Array.forEach (native)
>>   at Object.module.exports (/Users/admin/Sites/new/docroot/Gruntfile.js:24:11)
>>   at loadTask (/Users/admin/Sites/new/docroot/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:315:10)
>>   at Task.task.init (/Users/admin/Sites/new/docroot/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:434:5)
>>   at Object.grunt.tasks (/Users/admin/Sites/new/docroot/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:111:8)
>>   at Object.module.exports [as cli] (/Users/admin/Sites/new/docroot/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/cli.js:27:9)
>>   at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt:44:20)
>>   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>>   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>>   at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>>   at startup (node.js:119:16)
>>   at node.js:929:3

No tasks specified, running default tasks.
Running tasks: default
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I am not very familiar with Grunt so that doesn't help *me* too much but it might for someone else. So apparently the Gruntfile.js is OK but it can't register my tasks for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up completely reinstalling node and npm and the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

You need a newer version of nodejs. The one included in my copy of RHEL6 wasn't compatible with my Gruntfile.

I added the version from nodesource with this:

```
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
```

I removed the existing nodejs and grunt first, but then I went through the install with this version and ended up with grunt-cli v1.2.0, node v6.13.1, and npm v3.10.10. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

make `grunt-config.json` file with this content in your root of Magento:

```
{
    "themes": "dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes"
}
```

PS. and you must have your theme defined in:

```
ROOT/dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js
```

Hope this helps,
Regards

Comment: As I said, I followed all steps in [the docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/tools/using_grunt.html) so that includes this part. I have also tried with a *custom config file* as instructed there but the same happens. I will edit my question and include the contents of my `themes.js` file.

Comment: Oh, ok, but check your config and theme.js config,
Thanks, i'll waiting for Content theme.js

Comment: Thanks, I checked all I could so far. I have updated my question now.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. Running the command `grunt less:[theme]`, even with node 9.9.0, npm 5.6.0, grunt 1.0.2, and grunt-cli 1.2.0, I was getting

```
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected Token :
```

or, using the `--verbose` flag:

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> /[path]/package.json.sample:2
>>     "name": "magento2",
>>           ^
```

which was obviously a valid piece of JSON. For me in particular, the hint was in the filename: `package.json.sample`. I had previously executed the command `ln -s` creating a symlink from `package.json` to the aforementioned `.sample` file, but when I instead created a full copy of the file, the error disappeared.

If I had to guess, I bet the issue arose because I'm mounting my virtual Linux filesystem into Windows, and Windows handles linked files very differently.